# Using CCS Toggle LED With Button

Tags: c, pic, gpio, led

I didn't understand what is wrong with my code. Here what I am trying to do is toggle a led when I press button. And I count my button hits with `int count;`.
If the count number is even LED is high and else LED is low. But when I upload this program, LED stays on. And off only while I hold the button.

```
while(1){
int buttonState=input_state(pin_a0);

   if(buttonState != lastButtonState){
   count++;
   lastButtonState=buttonState;
     
      if(count%2==0){
      output_high(pin_b0);
      }
      else
      output_low(pin_b0);
}
delay_ms(50);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your button active-high or active-low ? Is your LED powered active-high or active-low? You need to give that information. 
I'll give an explanation assuming LED is powered when output is low. Then what follows is, assuming button is active-low, when your button is not pressed,

```
buttonState = 1;
```

So, since

```
lastButtonState = 0;
```

(at the start of the program, I'm assuming)

You will enter the if clause:

```
if(buttonState != lastButtonState){
...
}
```

This will increase your counter by one and make `lastButtonState = buttonState;`

Since `count%2` will be `1`, your pin will be `output_low(pin_b0);`... So, at the start of your program, your LED will be ON.

If you then press the button,

```
buttonState=0;
```

will happen and you will enter the if() clause, again. This will increase your counter by one. And then:

```
count%2 = 0;
```

Will happen. So, you will have

```
output_high(pin_b0);
```

As you can see, when you press the button, your LED will go off. And on when you release the button, your LED will go on Try this:

```
while(1){
   int buttonState=input_state(pin_a0);

   if(buttonState != lastButtonState){
   lastButtonState=buttonState;

      if(buttonState == 1){
          output_high(pin_b0); // LED is off
      }
      else
          output_low(pin_b0); // LED is on
   }
delay_ms(50);
}
```

You don't need the counter.

EDIT:

I see you have made this addition to your code:

```
if(buttonState==1) 
   count++;
```

This works. Yet is harder to understand. Try writing something easier to read.

Comment: Actually I checked the code on my controller. It end up with same result :D. Now initially it is high, after I press the button it goes low. And only I press to the button it goes high.

Comment: @iraquois Can you describe active-low or high of button and LED?

Comment: @iraquois If the code is initially high and then becomes working normally, then perhaps you didn't initialize the values buttonState and lastButtonState  as 0 starting your program. If you don't initialize, they may have arbitrary values.

Comment: my button is connected to 5v dc source and it is connected to the ground with 10k. I took the input from between button and 10k. and output from controller.

Comment: So when you press the button, buttonState = 1?

Comment: For a moment it is 1 and then it goes 0 ?

Comment: what i didnt understand is it shouldn't execute first if statement. Because initially buttonState and lastButtonState are equal.

Comment: This could be because mechanical buttons have debounce. So when you press a button, you see the voltage jumping from 1 to 0 over and over a couple times. Then it settles on 1. Is that what you are seeing? If you see it settle to 0, then you have a hardware problem. (Or software in reading button input)

Comment: Yes I think there is no problem with your code. Then I will handle with it mechanically. :) Thanks again. Discussion was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your logic. You have two changes while pressing the button. The first change is from 0 to 1 (pressing) and the second change is from 1 to 0 (releasing the button).

Try something like:

```
if(lastButtonState == 0 && buttonState == 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I solved the problem. Here I add 
          **if(buttonState==1)
           count++;**